# DB Oracle 11g BenchMarking

Tags: oracle11g

I'm experiencing some performance problem on a Oracle DB hosted by a virtual server.

Is there any tool for benchmark of Oracle DB or for gathering information about performance?

Thanks,
Andrea

Answer (score 1):

Enter STATSPACK, STATSPACK analyzer and Quest BenchmarkFactory into your search engine.